# Efficient way to select from table where condition1 OR invert condition1

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a table of **symmetrical** user relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_a` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_b` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

this table contains following info:

- user whose ID is 1 is a friend of user whose ID is 2
- user whose ID is 3 is a friend of user whose ID is 1

concludes that:

- user whose ID is 1 has 2 friends (ID 3 and ID 2)
- **user's ID can be in either of 2 columns** (see at user ID 1)

How do I make an efficient query to check if user 1 is a friend with user 3?

Why I'm asking about an efficient way? Well, because I have 3 different solutions (there might be even more) but I'm struggling to select the most efficient of them all.

Approach 1:

```
SELECT user_b AS user_a
FROM    friends
WHERE   (user_a = :user_a AND user_b = :user_b)
UNION ALL
SELECT  user_a
FROM    friends
WHERE   (user_b = :user_b AND user_a = :user_a)
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_a = :user_a AND user_b = :user_b) OR
(user_b = :user_a AND user_a = :user_b)
```

Approach 3:

```
SELECT user_a FROM (
SELECT user_b AS user_a
FROM    friends
WHERE   user_a = :user_a
UNION ALL
SELECT  user_a
FROM    friends
WHERE   user_b = :user_a
) AS newtab WHERE newtab.user_a = :user_b;
```

PHP check:

```
$my_id = 1;
$friend_id = 3;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ..."); // approach 1 or 2 or 3 or ...
$stmt->bindParam(':user_a', $my_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_b', $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
echo "You are friends";}
else { echo "he is not your friend";}
```

Performance-wise, which approach is better?

### Edit

**Test**:

```
$start_2 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
$end_2 = microtime(true);
```

**Results**:

> 1 : 0.14095306396484
>
> 2 : 0.063449859619141
>
> 3 : 0.18946194648743

Comment: performance questions usually end up being "benchmark it and see for yourself". since neither of your user_a/user_b columns have indexes, you'll end up doing full-table scans anyways, regardless of the solution.

Comment: @MarcB i followed your advice and implemented the benchark. winner is approach 2 ;)

Comment: How about `SELECT *
  FROM friends
 WHERE     (user_a = :user_a OR user_a = :user_b)
       AND (user_b = :user_a OR user_b = :user_b)
 LIMIT 1;`

Comment: just tested - no difference ;) (same result as approach 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already found out through tests approach 2 is going to be faster.

My take on the reason for this is that in 50% of the cases the first part will be enough to satisfy the `WHERE` part and the second part will not be executed at all.

Adding the idea from @Luis where you always have user_a < user_b those 50% will rise to 100%.

Also, joins and subqueries might need temporary tables and sometimes they even have to be on disk. This is really slow so it should be avoided.

To test if the query uses a temporary table run `EXPLAIN` and look for *using temporary* in the **extra** section.

I would also get rid of that extra id (useless data) and put user_a, user_b as primary key. That would give you an index that is fast (as long as you know that user_a < user_b).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an index for the usersID, and check if you really need the extra ID.

I would use option 2 for simplicity, not sure if its the most efficient way, you could test witch one is faster simple enough.

I had to do something similar to this once where the select querys where a lot more common than inserting, and had a lot of records, so what i did was always insert in a specific order, in this case could be something like user_a < user_b, so you could only check one side in the query.

Comment: basically I got 2 tables: first is for members (id, name, surname), second is for relationships (id1, id2). That way, I can establish friendship between 2 users. Is there any better way to do it? "One side query" approach that you were talking about is good - but that means that table will have twice as more records

Comment: not it does not mean that, it only means that if 1 is friend with 3, it could only be in this mid table, 1 id will always be in user_a and 3 will be in user_b, because 1 < 3

Comment: oh, right! I was thinking about something different but now I see your point! basically I have to compare IDs and put them according to "X < Y" method. Brilliant idea, I'm going to implement it. Thanks!